# Pivot table for string in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have the following table with some details as shown below:

**Example**:

Creating table `product`:

```
create table product
(
  slno int,
  item nvarchar(20)
);
```

Inserting some records:

```
insert into product values(1,'HDD');
insert into product values(2,'PenDrive');
insert into product values(3,'RAM');
insert into product values(4,'DVD');
insert into product values(5,'RAM');
insert into product values(6,'HDD');
```

Table product contains:

```
select * from product;

slno  item
---------- 
 1    HDD
 2    PenDrive
 3    RAM
 4    DVD
 5    RAM
 6    HDD
```

Now I want make a string of items for which i have written the following script:

```
select distinct 
(
   select distinct item+','
   from product
   FOR XML PATH('')
) temp
from product;
```

Result is:

```
 temp
----------------------
DVD,HDD,PenDrive,RAM,
```

**Note**: Now I want to show the result in the following format: (In which I need to use the `pivot table` with the above query and need to display how many product have sold out).

```
DVD  HDD  PenDrive  RAM
-----------------------
 1    2      1       2
```

**My Try**:

```
 select DVD,HDD,PenDrive,RAM
 from
 (
      select distinct 
      (
         select distinct item+','
         from product
         FOR XML PATH('')
      ) temp 
 from product
 ) as a
 pivot 
 (
    count(temp)
    for temp in(DVD,HDD,PenDrive,RAM)
 ) pt
```

But getting result :

```
DVD  HDD  PenDrive  RAM
------------------------
 0    0      0       0
```

Comment: @RafalZiolkowski, Plz check out my try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the `FOR XML PATH` to create a string of the columns unless you need a dynamic SQL version to get your final result.

Using PIVOT you can easily hard-code your values for your query:

```
select DVD, HDD, PenDrive, RAM
from
(
  select item
  from product
) d
pivot
(
  count(item)
  for item in (DVD, HDD, PenDrive, RAM)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d973c/3/0).

Now if you had an unknown values that you needed to be the final columns, then you'd create a list of the `items` and execute a SQL string via dynamic SQL similar to:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(item) 
                    from product
                    group by item
                      order by item
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
                select item
                from product
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                count(item)
                for item in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d973c/5/0)

Comment: Exactly, I need to run dynamic SQL query to get result.

Comment: @Meem I thought so, so I already added a version that does that.

Comment: Yup! I got it. Thank you so much for your valuable assistance.